# JQuery To Insert Multiple GridViews into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have the below syntax - which works for inserting my gridview1 (with the C# code behind) but how could I alter this to work for both my gridview1 and gridview 2?

if I need to add my logic for my code behind I will, but I feel this is more related to the JQuery aspect than the code behindl

```
<div>
<div id="dgvGrid1" >
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#ffbf00" />
        <Columns>                    
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Q" HeaderStyle-Width="50%"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tim" HeaderText="Tim Answer" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tom" HeaderText="Tom Answer" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
     <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Save Row Data" />
</div></div>
<div>
<div id="dgvGrid2" >
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#ffbf00" />
        <Columns>                    
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Q" HeaderStyle-Width="50%"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tim" HeaderText="Tim Answer" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tom" HeaderText="Tom Answer" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
     <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Save Row Data" />
</div></div>
```

And the jquery portion of it

```
<script>
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        var qna = [];
        var timdata = false;
        var tomdata = false;
        $('[id*=GridView1]').find('tr:has(td)').each(function () {
            var gridrow = $(this);
            var colno = 1;
            var qnav = {};
                if ($(this).prop('checked'))
                {
                    if ($(this).val() == 'Q') {
                        qna.Q = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'tim')
                    {
                        timdata = true;
                        qna.Tim = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                    else if ($(this).val() == 'Tom') {
                        tomdata = true;
                        qna.Tom = gridrow.find("td:nth-child(" + colno + ")").html();
                        colno = colno + 1;
                    }
                }

            });
            qna.push(qna);
        });
        console.log(qna);
        if (qna.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("About.aspx/SaveGridViewRowData") %>',
                data: '{qna: ' + JSON.stringify(qna) + ', f2: ' + f2 + ', f3: ' + f3 + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: Well your aspx markup is invalid because you can't have two controls in the same page with the same ID, you gave your gridviews the same ID. It won't compile. Should we assume you intended to call it gridview2? Anyway you'll be wanting to refer to the new ID in your JS as well, and getting the same information from it, if they have the same structure.

Comment: you can did it in code-behind by the way what is your specific problem?

Comment: @ADyson - yes they both ahve the same structure.  Speed wise would I be best to just copy paste the code and change the id of the grid that I am looking at?

Comment: yeah that's the dirty approach. Better still, make a re-usable function to which you pass the ID of the grid you want to work on. Then call that function as many times as you have grids, with the different IDs

Comment: @ADyson -> smart thinking.  I like it!

Comment: @BoJackHorseman standard code re-use :-) Should be the first thing you think of from now on whenever there's a repetitive task to be done

Comment: @ADyson - I am using this syntax on the button click event on my page.  In this instance, rather than having a the same function called multiple times - would it be just as quick to create a JQuery array to hold each of the gridview names and iterate that array in one <script>?

Comment: yeah, although you could have it loop through the array of gridview names, and call the function each time, or yeah just put the code inside the loop. In this case it probably makes no substantive difference if you aren't going to re-use the code somewhere else as well.